Why am I not getting 1000 results from PRAW?
My understanding is that you can get up to 1000 results from the Reddit API using asyncpraw. I'm getting only 232 results, rather than the full 1000. Does anyone know why this is happening? I'm trying to get back to 2019, starting from the present. (I'm only getting back to February 2020.)
# !pip install asyncpraw
import asyncpraw
import asyncio
import datetime

# Initialize
reddit = asyncpraw.Reddit(
    client_id = "TODO",
    client_secret = "TODO",
    user_agent = "TODO",
)

subreddit = await reddit.subreddit("Ohio")

res_search = []

async for submission in subreddit.search("protest", limit=1000, sort="new", time_filter="all"):
    # Save the submissions (interim)
    res_search.append(submission)

min_date = min(
    [datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(submission.created_utc) for submission in res_search]
)

print(len(res_search))
print(min_date)

